# Blocking the high pitch sound from laptop power supplies

Tags: power-supply

Many power supplis for electronics, especially laptops, emit a veey high pitched noise. While for the most part this soind is too quiet to bother anyone it can sometimes become obnoxious.

The simple solution is to unplug it, but if you need to be using the system for an extended period it needs to be plugged in.

Is there anything that can be done to reduce the noise? I thought of insulating it somehow, but anything that could block the noise seems like a potential heat dispersal problem. Not to mention that the sounnd seems to penetrate anything I have tried to cover it with.

Comment: By obnoxious, I mean headache inducing that is. Leaving the room imediatly helps the head, but it doesn't get work done.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have to either deal with it, or seek a replacement. Sometimes it can be a sign that the parts are being stressed. I know the Voltage Regs on my Radeon HD7970 start screaming under load, and I know how annoying the sound can get.

Insulating an active component which has high dissipation, such as the various transistors, resistors, inductors and transformers (Basically an inductor as well) will definately increase its heat, thus shortening its capacity. Don't do that.

Another reason may be a faulty/low quality part. While the active switching devices (i.e: transistors) are expected to make noise, sometimes it is just silly. If the charger is under warranty, make a complaint. If not, maybe look at a third party generic model, a reputable one at that. It is amazing how much worse [cheap power supplies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wi-b9k-0KfE) can be for your devices, so avoid them like the plague.

Comment: I had contacted the one manufacturers and they said the noise was perfectly normal. So they aren't going o replace it.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the coils (inductors) by epoxy. It will probably break your warranty and requires a steady hand.

Comment: This does not provide a decent answer. How would you go about opening the transformer and muting the sound by introducing  epoxy into the former?

Comment: @Tog: It's exactly what I'm talking about. Open the case, find which inductors make that noise, fill them with epoxy (or change them for epoxied ones - this lead us to soldiering), glue the case, wait 24h for epoxy and pray that it will work.

Oh, and be careful: High Voltage :)

Comment: Ya, this seems like a great way to break something.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple, and low cost way of stopping this: rubber bands.

The other answers here involve disassembling or replacing parts.  That's a valid long term solution if you have the skill or cash.  If not, read on...

I find that wrapping an elastic band (or hair tie) *tightly* around a component will often help to damp the high pitched squeal.   An easy way to test this is to lightly squeeze the plug with your fingers - if that reduces the noise, tightly wrap a couple of bands around the casing.

Be careful not to block any air vents, and ensure that you don't prevent the plug from sitting flush in the socket.

This doesn't always dampen the sound 100%, and it is at best a temporary solution, but it does does work.

Comment: In this case I am talking about the power bricks that are connected by two cords (one to the computer, the other to the wall). I tried to squeeze them as you described but that produced no change.

Comment: Ah. In which case, I'd see if they're still under warranty.